# Google Sheet Query Formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Is there any way that without importing the data in helping sheet we can use vlookup as I have created in Sheet1 to lookup the values from other sheet “Directly” by using IMPORITNG (Query formula?
Here is current formula.

=ArrayFormula({"Comments";IF(A2:A="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2:A)&B2:B&"|"&C2:C&D2:D,{TRIM('Sheet1 Import'!A2:A)&'Sheet1 Import'!B2:B&"|"&'Sheet1 Import'!C2:C&'Sheet1 Import'!D2:D,'Sheet1 Import'!E2:E},2,FALSE),"*** NOT FOUND ***"))})

But above formula is taking the data from helping sheet I am trying to create a formula that directly match the result and take relevant data from another sheet.

I have created this formula but its not working ?

=INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x7ofB9Rt-y5_DlaxQVIZK_ZKR8sqBHVxAu3ZZlU13YA/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!E:E"),MATCH(1,(A2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x7ofB9Rt-y5_DlaxQVIZK_ZKR8sqBHVxAu3ZZlU13YA/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!A2:A")(B2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x7ofB9Rt-y5_DlaxQVIZK_ZKR8sqBHVxAu3ZZlU13YA/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!B2:B")(C2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x7ofB9Rt-y5_DlaxQVIZK_ZKR8sqBHVxAu3ZZlU13YA/edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!C2:C"),0)))))

Sheet links

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x7ofB9Rt-y5_DlaxQVIZK_ZKR8sqBHVxAu3ZZlU13YA/edit#gid=0

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_9Vumt1a-1WnrXAHOpJd1GUTQ3jLjPifwGyKlDDRyi0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can someone please resolve the issue. Team (Stack overflow)

Comment: Can you explain better? See [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, sheet1 has data in 5 columns and Sheet2 has data in 4 columns and i want to get the column 5 data from sheet1 to sheet2 after matching that both sheet "  "member Name", "Member Date of Birth", "Member ID", :Skill" are similar then it should mention the result.

Comment: It is same as vlookup works but vlookup just match the single value i want to match the 4 value then result should be pasted.

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clear what is being asked also add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Done i modified with brief details.

Comment: In this case I think something that would help us understand is a "from -> to" scenario. (I have "this data here" and I want a result that looks like "this here", I attempted "this" and failed "here". Also I believe the sheets are not editable, can you make them editable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question

> Is there any way that without importing the data in helping sheet we can use vlookup as I have created in Sheet1 to lookup the values from other sheet “Directly” by using IMPORITNG (Query formula?

One way is to add the VLOOKUP formula on the source spreadsheet then import the result. Another way is to use Google Apps Script.